# Emacs list is not a list

Tags: emacs, elisp

This code evaluates to `t`

```
(listp '(foo 0 . 0))
```

These code gives an error: `eval: Wrong type argument: listp, 0`

```
(mapcar (lambda (x) x) '(foo 0 . 0))
(length '(foo 0 . 0))
```

All three are using the same "list", but `mapcar` and `length` clearly do not think that it is a list.  This is because the list ends with a `0 . 0` rather than `0 0`, although I do not know why that makes a difference to `mapcar` but not `listp`.

Is there a way to modify the mapcar expression to accept both regular lists like `(foo 0 0)` and these cons-style lists `(foo 0 . 0)`?  In the actually application, my input has both types of lists (*e.g.*, `("a" (b 0 . 0) (c 0 . 0))` and the lambda is a recursive function that calls `mapcar` if its argument is a list.

(In case the previous paragraph was not clear, the answer "use `(foo 0 0)` instead" is wrong.)

I suspect the answer is something like

```
(defun my-func (x) 
  (if (consp x)
    (if (not-actually-a-list-p x)
      (delistify (mapcar #'myfunc (listify x)))
     (mapcar #'myfunc input))
   ; process the individual atoms
   ))
```

However, I do not know what `not-actually-a-list-p`, `listify` and `delistify` should be.

Comment: I am really tempted to say "use (foo 0 0) instead", but you surely have your reason :-)

Comment: @coredump My input is  c-style-alist`.  It's not really under my control.  (If it was under my control, I would just change it rather than try to search it for problems and patch it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason `listp` returns `T` is because it only checks whether the argument is either `nil` or a cons-cell. A *proper list* is either `nil` or one where all `cdr` satisfy `listp`.

`mapcar` and `length` actually have to iterate the list and choke on improper lists, because they cannot take the `cdr` of something not being a cons-cell.

You only need to implement `mapcar-dot` to solve your problem. For example, here is a recursive approach:

```lisp
(defun mapcar-dot (f list)
  (typecase list
    (null nil)
    (cons (cons (funcall f (car list))
                (mapcar-dot f (cdr list))))
    (t (funcall f list))))
```

Example

```lisp
(list (mapcar-dot #'1+ '(1 2 3 4))
      (mapcar-dot #'1+ '(1 2 3 . 4)))
=> ((2 3 4 5) (2 3 4 . 5))
```

Here, I preserve the original structure, meaning that improper lists as inputs give improper lists as outputs. I don't know if this is what you want. In case you want to always return proper lists, then simply do:

```lisp
(defun mapcar-dot* (f list)
  (loop for (a . b) on list
        collect (funcall f a)
        unless (listp b)
          collect (funcall f b)))
```

Comment: That was what I needed (including maintaining the improper structure).  (a . b) vs. (a b) is always confusing to me.

Comment: `(1 . 2)` is one cons cell containing 1 in its _car_ and 2 in its _cdr_. It might have been created with `(cons 1 2)`.  On the other hand, `(1 2)` is two cons cells. The first one contains 1 in its _car_ and its _cdr_ points to the second cell, which contains 2 in its _car_ and `nil` in its _cdr_. It might have been created with either `(list 1 2)` or `(cons 1 (cons 2 nil))`. HTH

Answer (score 2):

`listp` returns non-`nil` for a cons cell:

```
listp is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.

(listp OBJECT)

Return t if OBJECT is a list, that is, a cons cell or nil.
Otherwise, return nil.
```

`listp` does not check for a true list (i.e., with cdr of it last cons cell `nil`).

`mapcar` and `length` require that a list argument be a true list.

To apply `mapcar` to a list that might not be a proper list, you can do something like this:

```el
(defun my-map (fn conses)
  "Like `mapcar', but for a dotted list also."
  (let ((res  ()))
    (while (consp conses)
      (push (funcall fn (car conses)) res)
      (setq conses  (cdr conses)))
    (when conses (push (funcall fn conses) res))
    (nreverse res)))
```